# Accessing a collection twice from a single function in MongoDB using python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying out a confirmation function where someone gets multiple options but is allowed to choose only one, so I have to automatically set the previous confirmed value to `false`.

I have a collection named confirm:

```
{
    "_id": "test1",
    "day": "mon",
    "confirm": "false"
}
{
    "_id": "test2", 
    "day": "mon",
    "confirm": "false"
}
```

First time when `test1` is confirmed

```
{
    "_id": "test1",
    "day": "mon", 
    "confirm": "true"
}
{
    "_id": "test2", 
    "day": "mon",
    "confirm": "false"
}
```

If the confirmation is changed that `test2` is confirmed then it should be like

```
{
    "_id": "test1",
    "day": "mon", 
    "confirm": "false"
}
{
    "_id": "test2",
    "day": "mon", 
    "confirm": "true"
}
```

My function is:

```
def confirm(i,d):
    db.condirm.update({"_id": i},{'$set':{"confirm": "false"}},upsert=False)
    db.condirm.update({"_id": i, "day": d},{'$set':{"confirm": "true"}},upsert=False)
```

But when I do this its not working properly the second confirmation also becomes true.

The output looks like this:

```
 {
    "_id": "test1",
    "day": "mon", 
    "confirm": "true"
}
{
    "_id": "test2",
    "day": "mon", 
    "confirm": "true"
}
```

Is what am doing right?

Is there anyother way to do this?

Someone please guide me

Comment: What you seem to be lacking here is another identifier to say that these items should be a "pair" ( unless "day" truly is enough). If this were for say "booking" then maybe "room" might be appropriate. The basic case is to set the confirm status to true for the one you want, and then to set all others in the group with the common identifier to false. Also look at [Bulk](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations, as that is how you send multiple operations in a single request to the sever, rather than going back and forth for each.

Comment: I suspect that the bug is in the function which calls `confirm`.

Comment: @Philipp can you please explain

Comment: @TonyRoczz I suspect you are calling it with the wrong parameters or in the wrong order.